# Laravel Collective Old in Text Box

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Can you stop old from auto poplulating a text box on validation errors?

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'New Site Name']) !!}
```

I have tried putting a default in place of null but on validation error it ignores this and puts the value of old in there. Ideally I want it to just use my placeholder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel, but you might look at the autocomplete attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Thanks Pete. I tried that and it didnt work unfortunately.